# I don't understand a couple of symbols on this diagram

Tags: bluetooth

I'm trying to connect a XS3868 Bluetooth module to an Arduino. This is what the module looks like, the picture includes the pin names.
[image: the pin names]
I also found the following diagram online that explains how to wire it: 
[image: the circuit diagram]

There a couple of symbols in that diagram that I don't understand though:

- What does the symbol indicated in red and the 47u or 220u next to it mean?
- What is the part of the circuit indicated in blue trying to do? Why is there a capacitor?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Help I've gone colour blind - I see no red or blue symbols.

Comment: @Jim It must contagious..

Comment: @JImDearden That was dumb... I have edited my post to include the correct picture.

Comment: Red : electrolytic capacitors. Connect them right way round. Blue : hold the Reset pin low to reset the CPU on power-up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red = polarized capacitor.  The 47u = 47 microfarads.
Blue = poorly drawn, but the 220uF cap is likely the output cap for the internal 1.8V regulator.  The 10K + 100nF cap are an RC to keep the device in reset until the 1.8V output is stable.

Comment: What do you mean by "output cap"?

Comment: @ToddSewell, Your board has "input" from a battery, Vbat. Low left corner has a LDO voltage regulator, which apparently produces 1.8V "output". That's why the 220uF cap is called "output cap". And please don't ask what "LDO" means.